# Object assign to merge 2 array of object and keep self property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to merge 2 array of objects using Object assign. I know I can do this with map by comparing their ids, but somehow didn't worked in object.assign?

```
const ageArr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "age_range": "0 - 10 Years old",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "age_range": "11 - 20 Years old",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "age_range": "21 - 30 Years old",
  "value": 78
}]

const colorArr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "color": "#333"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "color": "#666"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "color": "#999"
}]

const mergedArr = Object.assign({}, ageArr, colorArr)
console.log(mergedArr)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6L2ceux

Comment: are the arrays ordered, that the id is always corresponding to the object with the same index?

Comment: @NinaScholz it doesn't matter right? as long as the ids of 2 arrays matched

Comment: Object assign does different thing, it makes prototype inheritance of Objects, not arrays.

Comment: @zb' `Object.assign` has nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: @Bergi https://jsfiddle.net/geLzdoss/ it is __proto inheritance

Comment: @zb' I think you were confusing that with `Object.create`. And no, your fiddle shows that `Object.assign` returns its first argument - `Parent === Child`.

Comment: yes, seems you right, brain fart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `map` method in combination with **Object.assign**

```js
const ageArr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "age_range": "0 - 10 Years old",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "age_range": "11 - 20 Years old",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "age_range": "21 - 30 Years old",
  "value": 78
}]

const colorArr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "color": "#333"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "color": "#666"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "color": "#999"
}]

const mergedArr = colorArr.map((item,i)=>Object.assign({},item,ageArr[i]));
console.log(mergedArr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know this but avoid it coz we don't use jquery.

Comment: @JessieAnderson, have a look now. I try map with Object.assign..solution in one line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and two loops.

```js
const
    ageArr = [{ id: 1, age_range: "0 - 10 Years old", value: 1 }, { id: 2, age_range: "11 - 20 Years old", value: 1 }, { id: 3, age_range: "21 - 30 Years old", value: 78 }],
    colorArr = [{ id: 1, color: "#333" }, { id: 2, color: "#666" }, { id: 3, color: "#999" }],
    map = new Map(ageArr.map(o => [o.id, o])),
    mergedArr = colorArr.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, map.get(o.id) || {}));

console.log(mergedArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For not same array length, you could collect first all objects with the same `id` in the map and render then result.

```js
var ageArr = [{ id: 1, age_range: "0 - 10 Years old", value: 1 }, { id: 2, age_range: "11 - 20 Years old", value: 1 }],
    colorArr = [{ id: 2, color: "#666" }, { id: 3, color: "#999" }],
    map = new Map,
    result;

[ageArr, colorArr].forEach(a =>
    a.forEach(o => map.set(o.id, Object.assign(map.get(o.id) || {}, o)))
);
result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hmm this is too complicated, do you have a more simple solution?

Comment: what means simple? a solution with more lines and an object for the reference to the same `id`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r8jdqe1k/ this is simple, but it might break if the ageArr has 4 items.

Comment: using find is a solution as well, but on large arrays it could take more time.

Comment: but how to solve the error if the item is not the same length?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` does not recursively merge objects. It just does shallow copies of object properties. In your case, it copies the values of the properties `0`, `1` and `2` from `colorArr` to the empty object.

Instead use a loop over your arrays and `Object.assign` to merge the individual items:

```
const mergedArr = [];
for (let i=0; i<Math.min(ageArr.length, colorArr.length); i++) {
    assert(ageArr[i].id === colorArr[i].id); // if they don't match you need to do a lookup
    mergedArr[i] = Object.assign({}, ageArr[i], colorArr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In case you just want to add both arrays into one you could try this:

```js
const ageArr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "age_range": "0 - 10 Years old",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "age_range": "11 - 20 Years old",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "age_range": "21 - 30 Years old",
  "value": 78
}]

const colorArr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "color": "#333"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "color": "#666"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "color": "#999"
}]

const mergedArr = ageArr.concat(colorArr)
console.log(mergedArr)
```

Remember that the concat function does return a new array and doesnt make any changes to any other array. Meaning colorArr and ageArr are unchanged after the concat() call.

Take a look at the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: this is not what I want.